# C++ application that stores the arrival time of ethernet frames

Tags: linux, library, c++, networking, network-monitor

I want to build a C++ application that stores the arrival time of ethernet frames in an SQLite database. I'd appreciate any advice on the best libraries or GitHub projects to use. I've already come across [libtins](http://libtins.github.io/tutorial/sniffing/).

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! [What's "best" is always subjective](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/157/185): *one man's trash is another man's treasure.* Better describe what would make this software *fitting best for you* – which then enables us to give fitting recommendations. See [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for more hints.

Comment: For instance, do you value accuracy of timestamp over perhaps losing a few packets? And, could you use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org) to capture, and export the logs? It already has a few decades of industry standard usage, and has some well written code to do exactly this (plus ***lots*** more). If you must code your own, then you can [get the source code](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/ChSrcObtain.html) and modify it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "best libraries to use" but I can also recommend [PcapPlusPlus](https://github.com/seladb/PcapPlusPlus). It does deep analysis of network packets including ethernet frames arrival time

Answer (score 1):

Wireshark will already capture packet timestamps. I believe it uses [PCAP](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap) internally for the low-level work.

See https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap